# Can Artifactory have a remote docker registry which proxy an old v1 docker registry?

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry

We are migrating from old docker registry (v1) to Artifactory.

We wanna create a virtual registry which include a remote registry (current v1 registry), a local registry (for new image) and docker official registry.

Seems Artifactory doesn't support remote registry of v1 registry. Is that possible to let Artifactory to support v1 remote registry?

Best Regards,
Eric Zhang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in Artifactory's Docker [Support Matrix](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-SupportMatrix) - docker V1 is supported only for local repositories (not remote nor virtual).
It seems you will have to first migrate your V1 images to V2... Of course you can do it by pushing your old images directly to a V2 repository in Artifactory.

HTH,
Yinon